# Webview to PDF ignores job name

Tags: android, pdf, printing, webview

I am trying to print an HTML-page from a webview on KitKat (4.4.4) basically using the sample code provided in [Google's API documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html). Accordingly, I set a print job name as follows:

```
String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, 
                        new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

My code runs fine and the page is printed as intended. Even if the user chooses the option "save as PDF" in the Android standard printing dialog, the codes renders a nice PDF and the user can choose a file name. At this point I would expect Android to use the string stored in the `jobName` field as file name. Instead it always uses `webview` as file name, although my code does not contain `webview` as string.

Is there a way to set another default name for storing a PDF file that is generated in my application?

Thanks for your hints...

**Update:**

I spent some additional time investigating this issue and I found that  the `WebView` uses `AwPrintDocumentAdapter`  as print adapter if the adapter is created by calling  `createPrintDocumentAdapter()` as proposed in the API documentation. That class then calls 
`PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("webview")` which seems to be the reason why the PDF always is named "webview". Some research reveals the following [code snippet](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium_org/+/1fd9e3b/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwPrintDocumentAdapter.java) in `AwPrintDocumentAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                     CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback,
                     Bundle metadata) {
  mAttributes = newAttributes;
  // TODO(sgurun) pass a meaningful string once b/10705082 is resolved
  PrintDocumentInfo documentInfo = new PrintDocumentInfo
  .Builder("webview")
  .build();
  // TODO(sgurun) once componentization is done, do layout changes and
  // generate PDF here, set the page range information to documentinfo
  // and call onLayoutFinished with true/false depending on whether
  // layout actually changed.
  callback.onLayoutFinished(documentInfo, true);
}
```

Hence, this seems to be the root cause for my problem - at least if that code made its way to my Nexus 4 test device... Finally, the best way to deal with this naming issue seems to be a custom print adapter implementation.

Are there any other solutions that do not require a custom print adapter (which should contain code for calculating the number of pages etc...)?

Comment: +1 Nice first question! Welcome to StackOverflow.